# Zend_Pdf - Text On Top of Shapes?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

Is it possible to draw text over top of a drawn shape with Zend_Pdf? No matter what order I execute the draw statements, the shape is always on top of my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw images first, save, then load document and draw text.